# hook_feeds_processor_targets_alter - how to set a value not in the feeds source?

Tags: feeds

I need to import a csv that has only two fields (**date** and **name**) to a content type that has 3 fields:

- date
- name
- file

The **file** field should be set as the name of the file being imported.

My code until now is this:

```
function MYMODULE_feeds_processor_targets_alter(&$targets, $entity_type, $bundle_name) {
  $targets['my_feed'] = array(
    'name' => t('field_filename'),
    'description' => t('This field has the csv file name.'),
    'callback' => 'mymodule_import_filename',
  );
}

function MYMODULE_import_filename($source, $entity, $target, $value, $mapping) {
    $my_filename ='file.csv';
    $entity->{'field_'.$target}[$entity->language][]['target_id'] = $my_filename;
}
```

Where am I doing a mistake? Is this the way to import a value outside the file being imported?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get the answer to this question.

In MYMODULE_import_filename() we can get the data we want to import, in my case is just a simple text: 'file.csv'.

The simple way to do it is like this:

```
function MYMODULE_feeds_processor_targets_alter(&$targets, $entity_type, $bundle_name) {
  $targets['my_feed'] = array(
    'name' => t('field_filename'),
    'description' => t('This field has the csv file name.'),
    'callback' => 'mymodule_import_filename',
    'real_target' => 'field_filename',
  );
}

function MYMODULE_import_filename($source, $entity, $target, $value, $mapping) {
    $my_filename ='file.csv';
    $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $entity);
    $wrapper->field_filename->set($my_filename);
}
```